# getAddress.autocomplete unable to resolve module

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble with adding the **getAddress autocomplete** module into my react app.
https://documentation.getaddress.io/JavaScriptAutocomplete

I get the following error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'getaddresss-autocomplete'

I installed the package and imported it into my component.

> npm i getaddress-autocomplete

> import getAddress from 'getaddress-autocomplete';

Tried with no joy..

> import autocomplete from 'getaddress-autocomplete';

Updated my app to use typescript.

Tried this a few times..

> rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install

But still I get not resolved.

I can see the package is in my modules/package.json, and I can access its dependence (getAddress-api) if I import that.

Any thoughts?

Sorry I have been googling for 5 hours now and no further forward with it!

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation about importing it. Have you added `<script src="https://cdn.getaddress.io/scripts/getaddress-autocomplete-1.1.3.min.js"></script>` like the documentation tells you to do?

Comment: Apologies for the delay.. I have tried this yes but with no joy